# Display events that appear at certain venue

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel, entries-field

I'm trying to work out how to query some channel posts (events) that take place at a certain venue.

```
{% set params = {
    section: 'events',
} %}
```

I have a 'eventVenue' field in my events section which is an entries field powered by a channel called venues. I want to query by venue ID?

Comment: Thank you, that solves the date issue. Any idea how to query by venue id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an [Entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/entries-fields), you're "relating" the entry to other entries.
The [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) parameter to filter by related entries is the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) parameter.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{% set params = {
    section: 'events',
    order: 'eventShowtime desc',
    relatedTo: venueId
} %}
```